How to remove the insert template option from LWC version of Global Send Email action
I have a lwc component. On click of a button I launch email composer with predefined values including body. Refer: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-quick-actions-email.html
Now I would like to know how to remove the insert template option from the composer view. It seems not possible. Has anyone tried or have idea how this can be done?

